# Why is there no error message appearing when using Yup's trim-method?

Tags: next.js, formik, yup

I am using Yup and Formik for my registration form. Somehow when using the trim method provided by Yup on my password there is no error message appearing, while all the other validation methods are working properly.

Here is the password part of my Yup schema:

```
password: Yup.string()
            .required('Password is required)
            .min(8, 'Password must be at least 8 characters long')
            .max(18, 'Password cannot be longer than 18 characters')
            .matches(
                /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])/,
                'Password must contain at least one number as well as one uppercase, lowercase, and special character'
            )
            .trim('Password cannot include leading and trailing spaces')
            .matches(
                /^(?!.*  )/,
                'Password cannot contain two or more consecutive spaces'
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation must be run in strict mode, otherwise the trim-method will transform the input instead of validating it. If strict is added it will check if there are leading or trailing spaces. Additionally, I found out that it can lead to bugs if type email is used in the html input field. The test-method and also the trim-method did not work when type email was set.